# How to select dates between specific range including closest available date outside of provided range in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a data

| DateTime | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-05 01:00:00+01 | 1 |
| 2021-02-05 01:15:00+01 | 2 |
| 2021-02-05 01:30:00+01 | 3 |
| 2021-02-05 01:45:00+01 | 4 |
| 2021-02-05 02:00:00+01 | 5 |
| 2021-02-05 02:15:00+01 | 6 |
| 2021-02-05 02:30:00+01 | 7 |
| 2021-02-05 06:00:00+01 | 8 |
| 2021-02-05 06:15:00+01 | 9 |
| 2021-02-05 06:30:00+01 | 10 |
| 2021-02-05 06:45:00+01 | 11 |
| 2021-02-05 07:00:00+01 | 12 |
| 2021-02-05 07:15:00+01 | 13 |
| 2021-02-05 07:30:00+01 | 14 |

Interval between each next row should be +15 min (sometimes they are missing).
I need to select interval between A and B and in case if A doesn't exist take first available value. For example

If I'll try to take DateTime `BETWEEN '2021-02-05 03:30:00+01' AND '2021-02-05 07:15:00+01'` system should return

| DateTime | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-05 02:30:00+01 | 7 |
| 2021-02-05 06:00:00+01 | 8 |
| 2021-02-05 06:15:00+01 | 9 |
| 2021-02-05 06:30:00+01 | 10 |
| 2021-02-05 06:45:00+01 | 11 |
| 2021-02-05 07:00:00+01 | 12 |
| 2021-02-05 07:15:00+01 | 13 |

It should return `02:30:00+01` as a nearest available row that is less then `2021-02-05 03:30:00+01`, because `2021-02-05 03:30:00+01` doesn't exist.

How can I achieve this result?

**What I've tried**

1. I've made

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2021-02-05 03:30:00+01' AND '2021-02-05 07:15:00+01'
```

and used `UNION` to join first row which is less then `2021-02-05 03:30:00+01` and ordered all result by DESC. Solution work well, but it is looks like there should be easier way to do that

2. I've used `generate_series` solution. I've generated date series with +15 minutes interval for a whole day, used left join from my table and filled score gaps by the first value, like this

| DateTime | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-05 02:30:00+01 | 7 |
| 2021-02-05 02:45:00+01 | 7 |
| 2021-02-05 03:00:00+01 | 7 |
| ... | 7 |
| 2021-02-05 06:00:00+01 | 8 |
| 2021-02-05 06:15:00+01 | 9 |
| 2021-02-05 06:30:00+01 | 10 |
| 2021-02-05 06:45:00+01 | 11 |
| 2021-02-05 07:00:00+01 | 12 |
| 2021-02-05 07:15:00+01 | 13 |

This solution is working well too.

Maybe I'm missing something and somewhere have much simpler solution to get first available row outside of `BETWEEN` range?

Comment: In fact, those are the solution that come to my mind too. You could try something using lead/lag window functions but I guess that wouldn't result in cleaner or more performant code...